# SQL: Ranking Using Ntile vs Percent_Rank

Tags: sql, r, rank

I am working with (Netezza) SQL through R.

Suppose I have the following data for the height of students. I purposefully simulated data so that are some outliers :

```
#R code
df1 = data.frame(id = 1:100, height = rnorm(100, 130,10))
df2 = data.frame(id = 101:110, height = rnorm(10, 220, 1))
df = rbind(df1, df2)
```

I can now simulate a local Netezza SQL connection and upload this dataset:

```
library(duckdb)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)


con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, df)
```

**My Problem:** I am interested in learning the differences between percent_rank vs ntile. For example, suppose I wanted to split the heights into 5 groups by percentile_rank and then comparing it to ntile.

As I understand:

- ntile(5) should take the shortest 20% students and put them in one group, etc. Each group should have the same number of students
- percent_rank() should divide the (max height, min height) into 5 groups - and then populate these groups. Each group might have a different number of students.

Here is a query which summarizes the data by percent_rank:

```
   query1 <- "
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    height,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY height) AS percent_rank
  FROM
    df
),
rank_groups AS (
  SELECT
    height,
    percent_rank,
    CASE
      WHEN percent_rank BETWEEN 0 AND 0.2 THEN 1
      WHEN percent_rank BETWEEN 0.2 AND 0.4 THEN 2
      WHEN percent_rank BETWEEN 0.4 AND 0.6 THEN 3
      WHEN percent_rank BETWEEN 0.6 AND 0.8 THEN 4
      ELSE 5
    END AS rank_group
  FROM cte
)
SELECT rank_group, COUNT(*) AS count, MIN(height) AS min_height, MAX(height) AS max_height
FROM rank_groups
GROUP BY rank_group"
percent_ranks <- dbGetQuery(con, query1)

  rank_group count min_height max_height
1          1    22   104.4292   122.9429
2          2    22   123.2100   128.2427
3          3    22   128.2786   131.6280
4          4    22   131.7928   139.9398
5          5    22   139.9988   221.7577
```

And here is a query which uses ntile:

```
   query2 <- "
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    height,
    NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS height_group
  FROM
    df
)
SELECT height_group, COUNT(*) AS count, MIN(height) AS min_height, MAX(height) AS max_height
FROM cte
GROUP BY height_group"
height_groups <- dbGetQuery(con, query2)

  height_group count min_height max_height
1            1    22   104.4292   122.9429
2            2    22   123.2100   128.2427
3            3    22   128.2786   131.6280
4            4    22   131.7928   139.9398
5            5    22   139.9988   221.7577
```

**My Question:** The results from query_1 are identical to query_2 - I would have thought they should be different. This is because the very tall students in percent ranks should be in their own smaller group - whereas in ntile they should be lumped with the tallest of the non-outliers.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can fix this?

**Note:** Here is how you can remove all files on the connection

```
   tables <- dbListTables(con)
    
    drop_commands <- paste0("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ", tables)
    
    
    for (command in drop_commands) {
      dbExecute(con, command)
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why you somulate ntile with the first, query change  the parameter of ntile and you will get other results